# How might I create a map in Go with tuples as values?

Tags: dictionary, go, tuples

How might I create a map that has strings as keys and tuples ,of one or many elements, as values?
The elements of the tuples are to be strings of phone numbers.
Much like what I have in the following Python code:

```
chicas = { "Alexia":("600000000"), 
"Paola":("600000008", "600000007", "600000005", "600000001", "600000004", "600000000"),
"Samanta":("600000009"),
"Wendy":("600000005")}
```

The variable `chicas` is meant to be immutable.
I've started with:

```
type chica struct {
  name string
  number tuple
}
```

but I get from Go: `undefined: tuple`.

Comment: Use a slice. Take the Tour of Go for language fundamentals.

Comment: In Go you can do `map[string][]string{"Alexia": {"600000000"}, ...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the size of your values are fixed, you can make a type like you have, or just use a map[string]string

Eg:

```
type MyTuple struct {
   key string
   value string
}

func main() {
  var x := make(map[string]MyTuple)
  x[“foo”] = MyTuple{ key: “bar”, value: “baz” }
}
```

Alternatively, you can do map[string][]string to make a map of strings to slices of strings, []MyTuple, or map[string]map[string]string to make a map of strings containing maps.